# Can you delay the Azure Dev Ops PR email notification to reviewers until after checks have completed?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, sonarcloud

In DevOps is there a way to delay or even cancel the email that is sent to PR reviewers until after the checks for that PR have been completed?

For example if you have a policy that checks for linked work items etc. I don't want to notify the PR reviewers until that is passed. I also have Sonarcloud PR analysis running so it would be nice to not waste the time of the PR reviewers if these checks where to fail, but I can't see a way of doing it which makes me think it isn't possible, but just thought I would check.

Comment: My gut feeling is no. Obviously you could just not add reviewers until you see the checks have passed, but that's more work for you to check back later. This sounds like a nice feature request.